# Bind several columns to one variable in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I moved my website to new server and found strange PDO behaviour:

```
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tabel SET info = :info, time = :date, active = :date");
$q->bindParam(':info', $info);
$q->bindParam(':date', $date);
$q->execute();
```

Only `time` column gets `$date`, and `active` gets nothing.
If I change them `active = :date, time = :date` then it became vice versa. Only first column receives variable. Others receive nothing.

What can be done, to make it send binded one `:date` to both columns? Without duplicating `:date1 :date2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to name and match all parameters to their values, so you'll have to go with something like what you said: `:date2` and make sure to bind them, so you'll end up with three bindParam statements.

See here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33886

:: it was a question of portability (just to share)

[edit/additional] ::
I'd like to suggest a better practice, though at the beginning it might seem like a lot of work: Why don't you use `stored procedures`? Check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

What this can help you do is to accept just the two values as parameters but use them in three column updates. Here's a sample:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertIntoTabel`
    (IN paramINFO VARCHAR(50), IN paramDATE DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tabel 
    SET info = paramINFO
    , time = paramDATE
    , active = paramDATE;
END
```

And then change your code to this:

```
$q = $db->prepare("CALL InsertIntoTabel (?,?)");
$q->bindParam(1, $info);
$q->bindParam(2, $date);
$q->execute();
```

It's only a suggestion, though. :)

Comment: I see it, it explains everything. But why most of the web servers are ok with this (i tired 3 different servers and my local one)?

Comment: Hold on.. you mean on the other web servers you're able to bind the $date value to more than one parameter? @Qiao :: by the way, I modified my post and shared additional info.

Comment: Yep, this is the first time (out of 4 on different web-servers) when multiple binding is not working. So, I am rewriting my code now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), the second argument of bindParam is mixed, maybe you could try this:

```
$date = array();
$q->bindParam(':date', $date);
```